# image processing in python - not working as well as I thought

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a picture that I want to scale it down. Therefore, I wrote this code:

```
def scaling_down(ima, value):
###~Scaling down the image by a value~###
value = int(value)
width, height = ima.size
mat_m = ima.load()
width2 = (int(width) + 1)/value
height2 = (int(height)+1)/value
out1 = Image.new('L',(width2,height2))
out_the_pix = out1.load()
for x in range(0,width,value):
    for y in range(0,height,value):
        out_the_pix[x/value,y/value] = mat_m[x,y]
return out1
```

The value is how much I want to scale the image down.
However, when I choose the value to be bigger than 2, I got errors. I need to choose the value 2 to receive no errors. Can you help me find why?

Comment: Is this PIL? You should fix the indentation in your question.

Comment: DRY, scikit-image have a function for this. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html?highlight=hough#skimage.transform.downscale_local_mean

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I get this error:
"
    out_the_pix[x/value,y/value] = mat_m[x,y]
IndexError: image index out of range
"

Answer (score 0):

out1 need to be bigger.

```
from math import ceil
width2 = int(ceil(1.0*width/value))
height2 = int(ceil(1.0*height/value))
```

This seemed to work with value of 3\4\5 atleast.

Some code to show why the original failed, Here with value = 3

```
>>>x = range(10)
>>>width = len(x)
>>>width
10
>>>width2 = (width + 1)/3
>>>width2
3
>>>for x in range(0,width, 3):
   .....:     print x/3
   .....:
0
1
2
3 <-- this would give the index error. Last index would be 2.

>>>widthLonger = (width + width%3 +  1)/3
>>>widthLonger
4
```

Comment: first, thanks. I got this error:
out_the_pix[x/value,y/value] = mat_m[x,y] IndexError: image index out of range
Why? What was the problem?

Comment: At the end of the loop, x/value and\or y/value ended up being a larger value than you had set for the size of out1.

Comment: @user3160249 See my edit for a more detailed example of where it would fail.

Comment: Value lower than 2? as in 1? If you want to start scaling by float factors, this becomes a new problem, and you would need a new approach.

Comment: but what if I want to use the float? I mean, 2.3 etc

Comment: tbh i'm not sure how to do that exactly. Best bet would be some browsing on google, you're most definitely not the first one who wanted to this. You might even stumble over a library that does it in one line ^^

Comment: Actually, PIL itself have a resize function. Why are you not using that?

Comment: it works perfect with float with the code above I wrote, the small problem is the thing that i get errors in values that are bigger than 2...

Comment: Well, the absolutely first thing you do in the function is to convert value to a integer... So sure you may give a float, but you're not really using a float are you then?

Comment: Now it works just for some seviral numbers.., for example - 1,2,3... 5, etc. check it out.

Comment: So there's a solution to this problem without changing the function?

Comment: Not if you want to use floats. Any reason why you wont use the previously mentioned resize function of PIL?

Comment: ok, without float.
Bcause I dont want to use the resize function of pil, I want to code it bymyself. so what now? as I wrote, your option was better than my original code but still had some problems.